# using shortcode attributes value in a separate php file

Tags: wordpress

How to use a shortcode attributes value  in a seperate php file
I have written a shortcode which acepts parameters file and type 
   [includefile file='membership-booking' mtype="group"]

```
function shortcode_includefile( $atts){
$data= shortcode_atts( array (
        'mtype' => 'post',
    ), $atts ) ;
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/shortcode_includefile/" . $atts['file']. ".php"; 
  if(file_exists($path))
    include $path;
  $code = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $code;

}
```

attributes file is fixed 'membership-booking' only mtype can be either group or individual.

Now in membership-booking file i want to read attributes mtype value.  on the basis of mytype value i need to echo something

Comment: You can use `$data["mtype"]` globally in included file. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23679975/using-shortcode-attributes-value-in-a-separate-php-file/23680669#23680669)

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you can use `mtype` like;

```
$mtype = $data["mtype"];
```

and you can use that variable globally like;

```
$mtype = "post"; // This is global 

function shortcode_includefile( $atts){
  $data = shortcode_atts( array (
        'mtype' => 'post',
    ), $atts ) ;
  $mtype = $data["mtype"];
  $path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/shortcode_includefile/" . $atts['file']. ".php";  // You can use $mtype in this file
  if(file_exists($path))
    include $path;
  $code = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $code;

}
```

Comment: I have declared $mtype global, but outside this function when i vardum p $mtype it is displaying NULL,

Comment: @RupaDas you are making big mistake. `$mtype` is local scope there that is why you are getting `NULL`. See my updated answer, `$mtype` is global now